# Puppet: Multiple manifests in module

Tags: puppet

I am trying to create `Puppet` module to setup my web server.

What i want - is to split configuration to logical modules (manifests by services: `webserver`, `database`, `ftp` etc.) But I can not figure out how to use additional manifests in `init.pp`

*I am going to use it only with `puppet apply` not server-client configuration.*

My text module manifest (kp/manifests/init.pp):

```
class kp {
    include kp::testfile
}

include kp
```

And additional manifest (kp/manifests/testfile.pp)

```
define kp::testfile {

    $value = template("kp/some.erb")

    file { 'testfile':
        path    => '/tmp/my.txt',
        ensure  => file,
        content => $value
    }
}
```

Documentation says:

```
If a class is defined in a module, you can declare that class by name in any manifest. Puppet will automatically find and load the manifest that contains the class definition.
```

But when I run `puppet apply init.pp` I am getting error message

```
Could not find class kp::testfile for myhost.com at /myDir/puppetModules/kp/manifests/init.pp:2 on node vagrant.example.com
```

Facts

- `/myDir/puppetModules/` is in `modulepath` so no problems here
- Puppet version v2.7.11
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kp::testfile is a defined type, not a class. To use a defined type you need to declare it like:

```
kp::testfile { 'name': }
```

Try redefining kp::testfile like

```
class kp::testfile {

    $value = template("kp/some.erb")

    file { 'testfile':
        path    => '/tmp/my.txt',
        ensure  => file,
        content => $value
    }
}
```

and you may have better luck.

Comment: Oh my god, i spend so much time on it and it is so simple. I have no idea now where from i got that example with "define" but i just didn't pay attention to it since i wrote it. Thanks, looks like now it works!